# How to Stop OnTouchListener while user is touching the screen ? < android>

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Hey I am looking for a way to force the user on-touch to be cancel and force him to raise his finger again to re-choice.

This is basically my question:

[image]

Comment: @JoeDF For android assume Java unless they say differently, since that's the language the SDK supports.

Comment: @Gabe I see... But at the Time of my post, Ontouchlistener was the only tag...

Comment: java for android application.

Answer (score 3):

#### Option 1:

set OnClickListener instead of OnTouchListener.

#### Option 2:

catch the ACTION_UP and apply your action only after it.

```
boolean pressFlag= false; 

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      if(pressFlag==false){
         // applay your action
         pressFlag==true;           
      }else{
         //do nothing
      }
      break;
    
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      pressFlag==false;
      break;
   
    default:
    break;

    }
  return true;
```

}

Comment: Thanks I've done that , but my situation is like that ,i have a few (Button slide ImageViews ) that come one after the other.
So when the user slide on button , and don't raise his finger the next button slide immediately to the position when the user left his finger.

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys thanks alot solve it via:

```
qlistener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (isTouced == false && event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    return false;
                else isTouced = true;
                ;
....
```